# To create MS Access text box in form in run time

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to create a form in MS Access where based on value we enter in a text box, that many text boxes will be created automatically. For ex, if value 3 is entered, three text boxes must be created.

Part of Code:

```
Dim box As Control
Set box = CreateControl("Form1", acTextBox)
```

But I get run time error "You must be in Design or Layout View to create or delete controls"

Is is not possible to dynamically create text boxes in MS Access. If we can, please suggest how to do.
Thank you

Comment: As the message indicates, you can only create new controls in design view. Additionally, there is only a limited number of controls, over a form's lifetime, even if deleted, that may exist. So, you should explain your scenario in detail, so suggestions can be offered.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating controls on the form based on a user entered requirement, you would normally have created as many controls as are needed beforehand (possibly positioning them correctly, and setting the tab order etc.), and then set their `.Visible` and `.Enabled` properties as required.

However, this is one of those instances where it may be that you are not using Access properly - any time that something is hard or difficult to do often means that you are not using it in the manner intended.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, But we are not aware what number it would be. Sometimes user can give huge numbers also (say 15). So is there any other alternative you could suggest. Please advise.

Comment: Simply put, you either have to have the controls already present (but hidden) on a form, or else to open the form in design mode to create the controls (which is a fair bit of work)/ There is no other way round this.